# Error: Ternary Operator not work correctly in "cout" object

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I'm making a C++ program that input a two-digits number, then print screen method to read that number by letter.
The problem that I'm facing is ternary operator. When I execute code below, output is 1 when input is 11, output is 0 when input is 12. I only post a paragraph of my program. I was shortcut it.
My code snippet :

```
switch(tens_position_value)
{
   case 1:
   {
        if (unit_position_value == 1|| unit_position_value==2)
        {
            cout << (unit_position_value == 1) ? "Eleven" : "Twelve";
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: `else if` --> `if`

Comment: Regardless of other issues you need parens around the ternary expression

Comment: Please do not add unrelated language tags to your question.  Many people think it will give their question more views but in the end you will only attract downvotes from people who you tried to "trick" into clicking your question desprite the fact that it doesn't even have anything to do with the tags they follow.

Comment: @ChrisG and a `break;` :)

Comment: I know, I only post a paragraph of my program. I was shortcut

Answer (score 2):

`<<` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `?:`, so the result of `unit_position_value != 1` (0 or 1) is printed instead of the strings. Add parentheses here:

```
cout << ((unit_position_value != 1) ? "Eleven" : "Twelve");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want to obtain, but I am supposing that if `tens_position_value = 1` and `unit_position_value = 1`, you want to print `"Eleven"`, while if `unit_position_value = 2`, you want to print `"Twelve"`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int tens_position_value = 1;
    int unit_position_value = 1;
    switch(tens_position_value)
    {
        case 1:
        {
                if (unit_position_value == 1|| unit_position_value==2)
                {
                    std::string result = (unit_position_value == 1) ? "Eleven" : "Twelve";
                    std::cout << result << std::endl;
                }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Bye ^_^\n";
}
```

In this case the output is `"Eleven"`, if you change the value of `unit_position_value` to 2, you obtain `"Twelve"`

Comment: Its work, but, why I cannot replace string by char. For example: 
char temp[]=(unit_position_value == 1) ? "Eleven" : "Twelve"; You can explain for me. Thank you